# Block quotes in blog posts do not render in chat one-boxes

Tags: bug, chat, blog, onebox

I [linked to a blog post](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/17629267#17629267) today in chat. That blog post contained a block quote, which appeared early enough to appear in the one-box. However, the text of that block quote was entirely omitted from the one-box.